# R: 'Error: unexpected '}' in "}"' --- due to whitespace?

Tags: r

```
foo <- function(x){x*2}
```

works fine in R Studio while

```
foo <- function(x){
   x*2
}
```

gives me the above error?!? I used  to move the code into different lines. Any idea why?

Edit: I am placing this code in the R Studio file editor and hitting "Run." Also

```
foo <- function(x){
  x*2}
```

returns: Error: unexpected '}' in "x*2}".

Comment: It works in my case. Actually you can avoid curly bracket here: `foo <- function(x)x*2` also works

Comment: Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Foolish me, hitting "Run" only runs the current line or selection, not the whole script. Selecting the whole function works.

Comment: Click "source" instead.

Comment: Also `Ctrl+Alt+F` runs the whole function.